# Failure when creating a kubeflow pipeline on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I successfully managed to create a kubeflow pipeline on GCP. I also have a very basic yaml file for the pipeline.

But when uploading the yaml file to create a new pipeline, I get an error that says the format of my pipeline name is wrong and that everything needs to be lower case or a '-'.

But the name I've selected is already in lower case, so I'm not sure why I get the error.

[image]

[image]